# React + Redux Example. Object are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am having trouble getting a simple React and Redux example working and need some help please. I am receiving the following error as soon as I attempt to dispatch the incrementNumber action. I will paste my code in below. [Or you can use the Github link here.](https://github.com/gabrielruss/redux-gabriel1) Thanks in advance!

[image]

index.js (App root)

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store/configureStore';

import App from './containers/App';

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

configureStore.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

export default createStore(rootReducer);
```

index.js (root reducer)

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import numbersReducer from './numbersReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    number: numbersReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

numbersReducer.js

```
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function numbersReducer(state = initialState.number, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "INCREMENT_NUMBER":
            return { ...state, number: state.number + 1 }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

initialState.js

```
export default {
    number: 0
}
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { incrementNumber } from '../actions/appActions';

export class App extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(incrementNumber(1));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Current number: {this.props.number}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    number: state.number
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

appActions.js

```
export function incrementNumber(number) {
    return { type: "INCREMENT_NUMBER", number}
}
```

Comment: can you post GitHub link or something with project structure?

Comment: I just added it, thanks for the tip. My brain is just fried at the moment.

Comment: It happens all the time with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
         Current number: {this.props.number.number}
</div>
```

and also change this.

```
export default function numbersReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "INCREMENT_NUMBER": {

            return { ...state, number: state.number + 1 }
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

/* state = initialState */

Comment: Thank you! I think I had just been looking at the code for too long. Silly mistakes haha!

Answer (score 0):

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    number: numbersReducer
});
```

In `combineReducers` argument object, `"number"` can't be property. Because `numbersReducer` already have this property `"number"` in it's `initialState`.